# HTML: set two columns in table wider than others by fixed number of pixels

Tags: html, html-table, width, multiple-columns

I have a table with `N` columns (`N >= 3`) that I want the columns be as follows:

- the leftmost (1st) column is `X` pixels wider than columns `2, 3 ... N-1`
- the rightmost (`N`th) column is `Y` pixels wider than columns `2, 3 ... N-1`
- columns `2, 3 ... N-1` are all of equal width, which changes when the container of the table resizes.

`X`, `Y` and `N` above are fixed numbers known before the page loads (they are constants).

How can I achieve that (either classic HTML/CSS or Bootstrap)?

Answer (score -1):

You can try this maybe

**page.css**

```
th{
  width: N width;
}

th:first-child{
  width: X;
}

th:last-child{
  width: Y;
}
```

if you don't have a header on your table you can change `th` by `td`

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not seem to work. It keeps the first column width of X and the last column width of Y, regardless of the total table width. What I want is that first and last column do get larger when the table gets larger, but in the same time they are still larger that "inner" column(s) by X and Y pixels, respectively.

Comment: Are you able to use JS ?